# ローカル環境でInstagram基本表示APIを表示させるにあたり、SSLサイト安全性チェックが必要になるのでしょうか？

Tags: php, api, instagram

初めまして。
プログラミング初心者で、現在人生初の実際の案件を作っています。お知恵を貸して頂けますと幸いです。

［環境］
・Windows
・VScode
・wordpressなどではなく、一から作っています

［現在の状況］
・雑貨屋さんのサイトを実際に作っている
・新商品入荷のお知らせを、インスタグラム基本表示APIで一覧にして表示させたい

## facebook開発者ページで使用するURLについて

こちらを参考にさせて頂いております。
[Instagram基本表示APIで投稿一覧を表示する手順](https://www.e-pokke.com/blog/instagram-basic-display-api.html)

### やってみたこと

[image: 手順]

一番最初から同じようにやれば出来るはず！！と思い着手し
前提条件で必要なものを確認・Facebook開発者アカウント、まずこれから作ってみようと思いました。

↓

1. Facebook開発者アカウントの登録を試みる

facebookアプリの作成にあたり、プライバシーポリシーのURLが必要になりました。
プライバシーポリシーはありますが、私はまだローカル環境でサイトを構築途中なので、ドメインなどはまだ取得していません。(wordpressを試した時に、Xサーバーやお名前.com、 FileZillaに触れたことはあります。)
http化する為にローカル環境の構築が必要ということが分かりました。

↓
2. XAMPPをインストールしてローカル環境を構築してみた

「localhostでなんとかなりますが頭が「https://」であることは必須のため、嘘でも良いのでhttps://を指定します。」という記事も発見しました。

XAMPPをインストールし、自身のサイトをローカル環境にアップ、そのURLをhttpsにして、facebook開発者ページの
「プライバシーポリシーのURL」欄に貼り付けました。

↓
3. エラー発生

「Facebookプラットフォームに準拠するものにするには、有効なプライバシーポリシーURLを入力してください。」
というエラーが出てきてしまい、次に進みません。

↓
4. とりあえず出たエラーを調べた

エラーを調べてみると、SSL証明書の発行が必要と出てきます。「SSL サイト安全性チェック」が出来るサイトもあることも知りました。
ここで心が折れます。
ローカル環境なのに、安全かどうかを証明する必要があるということでしょうか？

すみません、話す人がおらず…すごく初歩的な質問かもしれませんが
何かヒントを頂けますと幸いです…

==============

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 判らない事、困っている事を具体的に書いてください。
見ず知らずの人から「かなりハードルが高いでしょうか？」と聞かれて、適切な回答が出来る人は居ないと思いますので。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。具体的に記載させて頂きました。

Comment: 当該記事には「具体的なプログラムについては、ここでは示しませんが、必要な方は弊社にお申し付けいただければ、迅速に製作・納品させていただきます。」と書かれていますので、「手順がすっ飛んでいる」のではなく、意図的に伏せているのでしょう。

Comment: 参照した記事でまず読むべきなのは「前提条件」の段落ではないでしょうか。特に「ウェブサイトがあること」と「ウェブサイト上でPHPが動作すること」をあなたが理解しているのかが重要かと。

Comment: だんだん落ち着いてきました！！！ありがとうございます！少しずつ理解してきました…一個ずつ正しく手順通りにやってみたいと思います。

Comment: もしどなたかこの質問を見ていらっしゃいましたら、「そう」「そうじゃない」など簡単でも構いませんのでヒントを頂けますと幸いです…

Comment: このヘルプ [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) の内容に沿ってタイトルや質問を修正してください。まずは **具体的な問題をまとめたタイトルを書く** ことから始めましょう。

Comment: 本当にお手間を取らせてしまい申し訳ございません…修正してみました。

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が見つかるので何か参考になれば。[InstagramAPIからInstagram Basic Display APIへの移行](https://qiita.com/harapeko_momiji/items/446ab28c4f5c937d0962), [Instagramの写真一覧をサイトに表示する方法](https://illbenet.jp/view/get_instagram_by_GraphAPI_2020), [APIを使って自分のInstagram投稿写真を取得する方法【Instagram Basic Display API】](https://nandani.sakura.ne.jp/web_all/api-web_all/4804/), [【2020年度版】WEBサイトに埋め込んでいるInstagram(インスタグラム)の最新投稿一覧を表示されるようにする方法](https://note.com/webhikaku/n/n7e0186251133)

Comment: コメントや質問のやり取りをみるにご自身で進める気持ちも検索する能力もお持ちのようです。ただここは一問一答形式のQAになりますので、その度に質問を変更するのは残念ながらこのサイトの主旨に合わないように感じます。新しい質問は新たに投稿する必要があります。

Comment: それこそ質問者も理解しているとは思いますが、やろうとしていることは一記事あるいは本の一章ぐらいを消費する内容で、場合によってはそれは受託を受けれるレベルです。その内容を全体でこの一QAで賄うのは無理があるでしょう。もう少し問題をミクロにとらえてもうちょっと絞って質問してみてください

Comment: お手間をとらせてしまい申し訳ございませんでした…。ありがとうございました。頂いた参考URLをもう一度見てみます。